# how to get Recognized text only?

Tags: python, azure, speech-to-text

I used Azure speech to text in python

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk



var = lambda evt: print('ss: {}'.format(evt))
speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(var)
```

then after trying to get result actual recognizer text it end with this:

```
ss: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=0aea5e8b80e544b48414f2d27585b6c4, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=86c7de30436f4db1b064121bd617f24b, text="Hello.", reason=ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech))
```

I want to just print Hello ?

Comment: Why did you use the funciton `speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect` with a lambda callback `var` that be different from the classic usage of Azure Cognitive Service document? What type of your speech audio is, audio file, microphone or an url link of an online audio?

Answer (score 2):

To get the text from the event:

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk


var = lambda evt: print('ss: {}'.format(evt.result.text))
speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(var)
```

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. But I have been thinking if this is the right way to do it. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @VishalVenugopal: to extract the recognized text from the event using `evt.result.text` IMHO I think is the right way to do so as I haven't found an other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using simple mic to recognize the text, here is something which you can use to get the text:

```
def speech_recognize_once_from_mic():
    """performs one-shot speech recognition from the default microphone"""
    # <SpeechRecognitionWithMicrophone>
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
    # Creates a speech recognizer using microphone as audio input.
    # The default language is "en-us".
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)

    # Starts speech recognition, and returns after a single utterance is recognized. The end of a
    # single utterance is determined by listening for silence at the end or until a maximum of 15
    # seconds of audio is processed. It returns the recognition text as result.
    # Note: Since recognize_once() returns only a single utterance, it is suitable only for single
    # shot recognition like command or query.
    # For long-running multi-utterance recognition, use start_continuous_recognition() instead.
    result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()

    # Check the result
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        print("Recognized: {}".format(result.text))
    elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
        print("No speech could be recognized")
    elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
        print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
        if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
            print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
    # </SpeechRecognitionWithMicrophone>
```

Check [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/python/console) repo for further reference. Hope it helps.